# PHP Array structure to be changed

Tags: php, arrays

I'm in a foreach loop and i'm stuck with something...

I have this array:

```
if($nr_programare == 1) {
    $programare_start_old = strtotime('06:00');
    $programare_end_old_stamp = $programare_start_old+($durata*3600);
    $programare_end_old = date('H:i', $programare_end_old_stamp);

    $data['nr'] = $nr_programare;
    $data['sortiment'] = $sortiment;
    $data['cantitate'] = $cantitate;
    $data['start'] = '06:00';
    $data['end'] = $programare_end_old;
            $data['realizat'] = $cantitate_realizata;
} else {
    end($data);
    $programare_start_new = prev($data);
    $programare_start_new_stamp = strtotime($programare_start_new);
    $programare_end_new_stamp = $programare_start_new_stamp+($durata*3600);
    $programare_end_new = date('H:i', $programare_end_new_stamp);

    $data['nr'] = $nr_programare;
    $data['sortiment'] = $sortiment;
    $data['cantitate'] = $cantitate;
    $data['start'] = $programare_start_new;
    $data['end'] = $programare_end_new;
    $data['realizat'] = $cantitate_realizata;
}
```

And I would like to transpose it to this structure of array:

```
array_push($data, array($nr_programare, array($sortiment, $cantitate, $durata, $programare_start_new, $programare_end_old, $cantitate_realizata), $today.' '.$programare_start_new, $today.' '.$programare_end_old));
```

It has to look like this in the end:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $nr_programare
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => $sortiment
                    [1] => $cantitate
                    [2] => $durata
                    [3] => $programare_start_new
                    [4] => $programare_end_new
                    [5] => $cantitate_realizata
                )

            [2] => 11.03.2015 06:00
            [3] => 11.03.2015 10:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => $nr_programare
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => $sortiment
                    [1] => $cantitate
                    [2] => $durata
                    [3] => $programare_start_new
                    [4] => $programare_end_new
                    [5] => $cantitate_realizata
                )

            [2] => 11.03.2015 06:00
            [3] => 11.03.2015 10:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => $nr_programare
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => $sortiment
                    [1] => $cantitate
                    [2] => $durata
                    [3] => $programare_start_new
                    [4] => $programare_end_new
                    [5] => $cantitate_realizata
                )

            [2] => 11.03.2015 06:00
            [3] => 11.03.2015 10:00
        )

)
```

And so on...What do I need to do?

Comment: All the above code is in a foreach loop. The data is correct, I just need to change my array's structure to the desired one.

I have tried this:
array_push($data, array($nr_programare, array($sortiment, $cantitate, $durata, $programare_start_new, $programare_end_old, $cantitate_realizata), $today.' '.$programare_start_new, $today.' '.$programare_end_old));

But then, this lines are not good:

end($data);
$programare_start_new = prev($data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr=array ()
$last='';
foreach (....) {
if($nr_programare == 1) { 
    ($arr[]= array(
            [0] => $nr_programare
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => $sortiment
                    [1] => $cantitate
                    [2] => $durata
                    [3] => $programare_start_new
                    [4] => $programare_end_new
                    [5] => $cantitate_realizata
                )

            [2] => 11.03.2015 06:00
            [3] => 11.03.2015 10:00
        )
)
}else {       
  ($arr[]= array(
            [0] => $nr_programare
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => $sortiment
                    [1] => $cantitate
                    [2] => $durata
                    [3] => $last
                    [4] => $programare_end_new
                    [5] => $cantitate_realizata
                )

            [2] => 11.03.2015 06:00
            [3] => 11.03.2015 10:00
        )
)
    $last=$programare_end_new;
}
}
```

Then `$arr` will contain the array you are looking for

$last will change to the last $programare_end_new after each loop (where nr_programare != 1). You will have to change $last if you don't want it to be blank in the case that the first iteration is !=1

Comment: Hi. I am also trying to figure this out how to do it. If $nr_programare is not equal to 1, then I want [3] => $programare_start_new to be equal to the previous [4] => $programare_end_new.

Comment: the previous meaning from the last loop through?

Comment: Yes ambe5960. The current $programare_start_new has to be equal to the $programare_end_new from the previous loop.

Comment: hey ill edit my answer in a sec. let me know if it works

Comment: I've managed to do it this way:

end($arr[$nr_programare-1][1]);
    $programare_start_new = prev($arr[$nr_programare-1][1]);

Comment: Everything is ok now, can be closed. Thank you all for the help.